# Facing Issue in React Native and Android Studio

Tags: android, react-native

Would you please help me, I am stuck to create a new project in react-native Like below screenshot.
I have followed these steps:

1.npx react-native init HelloApp(projectName)
2.cd HelloApp(projectName)
3.npm run android

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DMXO0.png)

---

PS C:\android> cd HelloApp
PS C:\android\HelloApp> npm run android

> HelloApp@0.0.1 android
> react-native run-android

info JS server already running.
info Installing the app...
Starting a Gradle Daemon (subsequent builds will be faster)

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Unable to start the daemon process.
  This problem might be caused by incorrect configuration of the daemon.
  For example, an unrecognized jvm option is used.
  Please refer to the User Manual chapter on the daemon at https://docs.gradle.org/7.5.1/userguide/gradle_daemon.html
  Process command line: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_211\bin\java.exe -XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=512m -Xmx2048m -Dfile.encoding=x-windows-949 -Duser.country=KR -Duser.language=ko -Duser.variant -cp C:\Users\ȫ����.gradle\wrapper\dists\gradle-7.5.1-all\1ehga6e77gqps5uk2kc5kf1vc\gradle-7.5.1\lib\gradle-launcher-7.5.1.jar org.gradle.launcher.daemon.bootstrap.GradleDaemon 7.5.1
  Please read the following process output to find out more:

---

����: �⺻ Ŭ���� org.gradle.launcher.daemon.bootstrap.GradleDaemon��(��) ã�ų� �ε��� �� �����ϴ�.

- Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

error Failed to install the app. Make sure you have the Android development environment set up: https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup.
Error: Command failed: gradlew.bat app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

  at makeError (C:\android\HelloApp\node_modules\execa\index.js:174:9)
  at C:\android\HelloApp\node_modules\execa\index.js:278:16
  at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
  at async runOnAllDevices (C:\android\HelloApp\node_modules@react-native-community\cli-platform-android\build\commands\runAndroid\runOnAllDevices.js:109:5)
  at async Command.handleAction (C:\android\HelloApp\node_modules@react-native-community\cli\build\index.js:142:9)

---

Comment: Did you try to run it with --stacktrace to get more informations?

Comment: how to use it??